# Python Threads collection

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, return, python-multithreading

I have a code something like this,

```
import threading

class Mythread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):
            print('do some processing')

if __name__=='__main__':
       while Ture:
         val = raw_input('next thread')
         t = MyThread()
         t.start()
         t.join()
```

The question is how can I carry on with main function without blocking the main because `t.join()` stop the main until t does not finish?

Answer (score 0):

You should put code in the "code" tag or else it's not really readable.
And you just have to do something like that.

```
if name == 'main':
    #Thread creation
    allThreads = []
    while True:
        val = raw_input('next thread')
        newThread = MyThread()
        newThread.start()
        allThreads.append(newThread)

    #You can do something here

    #Waiting for all threads to stop
    for thread in allThreads: 
        thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, The main program always stay in while loop, how it will go the the #Waiting for all threads to stop?? I want the while loop (in main) to be forever, and need to collect the threads to stop. within the while loop.

Comment: Actually, What I want, I just want to start the thread, but don't want it to return to main. So when task in that thread finished it free that thread.